# The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake, openssl

I have a project which I tested first on Windows 10, and everything was fine, then I tested it on Windows 11, (using the same machine but booting in different OSs), and just after I finished testing with it, I could no longer make network requests, I keep getting these errors:

> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown Active TLS backend does not support key creation
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown Active TLS backend does not support key creation
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslSocket
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown The backend named "cert-only" does not support TLS
> W qt.network.ssl:  unknown unknown QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed

Every time I make a request, I get:

> "TLS initialization failed"

Linking OpenSSL in CMake:

```
set_target_properties(${GW_LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)

list(APPEND android_extra_libs
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../assets/libs/openssl/arm64/libcrypto_1_1.so
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../assets/libs/openssl/arm64/libssl_1_1.so)

set_target_properties(${GW_LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES
   QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS "${android_extra_libs}")
```

I tried my code in a different Qt project on Windows 10 and it successfully worked without any issues.

I am using:

- Qt 6.5
- Android NDK 25

Some forums recommend `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` `QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()` to get the OpenSSL version used by Qt, but when I tried it, I got totally different results.

Code:

```
qDebug() << "My build Version String is - "
         << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() << "  "
            " and version string is  "
         << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

Result:

> "My build Version String is - "Secure Channel (NTDDI: 0xA00000C)" and version string is  "Secure Channel, Windows 10.0.18363";

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using Qt 6.5, upgrading to Openssl 3 solved the issue!

For more, read [Qt Blog: Moving to OpenSSL 3 in binary builds starting from Qt 6.5 Beta 2](https://www.qt.io/blog/moving-to-openssl-3-in-binary-builds-starting-from-qt-6.5-beta-2), which says:

> As some of you might know, Qt6 supports [OpenSSL 3](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0) since Qt 6.2.0.
>
> Starting from the next (second) beta of Qt 6.5, our binary builds will be based on OpenSSL 3. Since OpenSSL 3 is a new major version, it is not binary compatible with OpenSSL 1.x, see this [link](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Versioning_Scheme).
>
> This makes binary builds in Qt 6.5 beta 2 and later binary incompatible with applications using OpenSSL 1.x. If your application is using OpenSSL, you would need to rebuild it on top of Qt 6.5 binary builds from the Qt Maintenance Tool in order to run it on top of Qt 6.5 binaries or use your own builds based on OpenSSL 1.x.
>
> This is especially important for Linux applications, since Windows and macOS have other API for secure communications in addition to OpenSSL.